# Mean line in plot

Tags: python, pandas, database, plot, mean

I have some plot with sale bike on prefer country. It looks like this:
[image]

This is my code:

```py
plot12.groupby(['Country','Year']).sum().reset_index()
ax = sn.barplot(x="Year", y="count", hue="Country", data=plot12)
mean = count.mean()
plt.axvline(mean, color='r', linestyle='--')
plt.title('Sprzedaż rowerów w wybranych Państwach')
```

I would like to put a mean line and next median line, but I get an error:

```
NameError: name 'count' is not defined
```

Comment: What is your  `count `?

Comment: This is my df :plot12 = df.groupby('Country')['Year'].value_counts().rename('count').reset_index()
plot12

Comment: Country Year count
0 Australia 2014 5774

Comment: So you never define `count` itself. That's why `count.mean()` throws an error.

Comment: So, how to put mean line from my value ?

Comment: I don't know, I suggest you create a minimal reproducible example, ie a small dataframe which people can play with, and then maybe someone will be able to help.

Comment: if count is in plot12, then plot12['count'].mean()